# variation part of the solving process for $xy’ -3y=x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

We have a differential equation: $xy’ -3y=x$

We solve this by solving homogeneous part, we get:

$$y =x^3D$$, where D is a parameter

When we solve the variation part we do: $y = D(x)x^3$

My question is the following:

$$y’ = 3x^2D(x) + D’(x)x^3$$
Then we get:
$$D‘(x)x^4+ 3D(x)x^3–3D(x)x^3 =x$$

and some terms cancel out.

I dont uderstand where we got the last equation from.

Comment: By inserting $y$ and $y'$ into $xy'-3y=0$.